# Dynamically hiding web parts based on current user roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts

How can I dynamically Hide/Show web-parts in asp.net. I am using [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1188712.aspx/1) to doing same , but In this article they have hard coded roles on AuthorizationFilter attribute of control , instead I want roles should be assigned at runtime. I have also tried another alternate , I have declare variable 'roles' in .cs file and at runtime assigning values to roles variable( and using like **AuthorizationFilter='<%# roles %>'** ) but it doesn't work for me as each time I am getting value for AuthorizationFilter as blank**(if I am using Text='<%# roles %>'** on label then it displays its value but value does not assign to  **AuthorizationFilter)**. I have also tried

```
     if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        Label2.Visible = true;
```

but it still display web part title inside web part zone.

Comment: share your some coding parts for better understand what you try??

Comment: I have exactly follow all steps shown in given link(in question) other modification are as            <cc1:WebPartZone ID="SectionU1" runat="server" EmptyZoneText="Show Item to this Section">
<ZoneTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AuthorizationFilter='<%# roles %>'></asp:Label> </ZoneTemplate> </cc1:WebPartZone>     and assign value to roles = "Admin" in .cs file Page_Load Method